# Dynamodb - Query max value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to find out if a user has created a transaction before.

I'm currently using python and boto3 to query a dynamodb table.I would like to query the max timestamp for a specific user to determine if the user has had a transaction before.

Something like `select max(timestamp) from transaction where userid = 123`

Is this possible?

Comment: Does the table have a composite primary key, with userid as the partition key and timestamp as the sort key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the timestamp is the sort key for your DynamoDB table:

```
aws dynamodb query \
--table-name my-table \
--key-condition-expression "#pk = :pk" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":pk":{"S":"leeroy"}' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#pk":"name"}' \
--no-scan-index-forward \
--limit 1
```

This `Query` will return the latest item for a given user by timestamp and is efficient.

Comment: which portion does the max timestamp?

Comment: You're ordering by timestamp, which is ordered lexicogrpahically if using strings, and `--no-scan-index-forward` reads the items in DESC order, meaning you will get the largest timestamp.

Comment: ... and because Limit=1, so you'll only get the 'last' item (which is the item with the highest sort key value i.e. latest date).